# Getting event object from Draw Toolbar onDrawEnd using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: dojo, events, map-drawing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the `Draw Toolbar` in the Esri Javascript API v3.4 and connecting to the `onDrawEnd` event using `aspect.after(drawingToolbar, "onDrawEnd", drawEndHandleFunction, true);`

I am using the `Draw Toolbar` with the `EXTENT` tool to allow my user to select features by drawing a box around them.  So far it is working fine.  However, I want the user to be able to add and subtract features from the selection using the `CTRL` and `SHIFT` keys while drawing.

I was able to do this in Chrome using the `event.ctrlKey` and `event.shiftKey` properties of the `event` global variable.  Firefox does not appear to have an `event` global variable like this and so my function doesn't work.  Firefox apparently passes an event as a parameter in the function, but that is not available because I used `dojo/aspect`.

Is there a better way to handle this?  Otherwise is there a way to get a map mouse event that triggers the `onDrawEnd` event in the `Draw Toolbar`?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/keys.html?highlight=keys#id2

There are some good Samples for Key-Eventlistener. Maybe it's useful.

Here's how i manage to listen for the EnterKey in a Textbox. I use the new dojo 1.8

```
require(["dojo/keys","dojo/dom","dojo/on"], function(keys, dom, on){
        on(dojo.byId("selectAnlagenNummer"), "keypress", function(evt){
            var charOrCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
            if (charOrCode == keys.ENTER) {
                zoomToAnlage();
            }
        });
    });
```

It's not a complete solution for your Problem, but maybe it shows a way.

Answer (score 2):

Attach to the keydown and keyup events. When the "draw-end" event fires
use the "IsShiftDown" to see if the shift was being held down.

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(on) {

    var IsShiftDown = false;

    on(document, "keydown", function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 16)
           IsShiftDown = true;
    });

    on(document, "keyup", function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 16)
           IsShiftDown = false;
    });

});
```